# Button is not displayed on JFrame after .setVisible(true) and ActionListener does sometimes not register clicks on buttons

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, actionlistener

To my two questions:

1) The last added Button 9|9 is displayed to big instead of the coded height and width (100 and 100).

2) Further the ActionListener does not always register the cklicked button at the first try, but rather changes the state/color after the second click.

Any suggestions?

```
static JFrame gui;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] colors = new int[81];
    for (int n=0; n<81; n++) {
        colors[n] = 0;
    }
    setupGUI(colors);
}

private static void setupGUI(int[] colors) {
    gui = new JFrame("9x9x9 LED-Cube GUI");
    gui.setSize(905, 925);
    gui.setResizable(false);
    gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for (int b=0; b<9; b++) {
            int bn = b;
            Button br = new Button((i+1) + "|" + (b+1));
            br.setBounds(b*100, i*100, 100, 100);
            gui.add(br);
            br.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
                    changeButtonColor(br, colors, bn);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    gui.setVisible(true);       
}

public static void changeButtonColor(Button br, int[] colors, int bn) {
    if(colors[bn] == 0) {
        br.setBackground(Color.green);
        colors[bn] += 1;
    }
    else {
        br.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        colors[bn] -= 1;
    }
    System.out.println(colors[bn]); //for test purposes to display the state change
}
```

Comment: Don't ever set bounds. Use a layout manager. Don't initialize an int array elements to 0: that's their default value. Don't represent an int to represent a boolean. Your colors array has 81 elements, but you're only using 9 of them.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much! - fixed both problems.